# SSL certificate in Glassfish 4.1

Tags: ssl, glassfish

I have a web applicaton in my glassfish server, the application has videos hosted in the same server with .mp4 extension, I added a GeoTrust SSL certificate for greater security in the application, when i play a video on an iPad using the HTML 5 video element works fine using HTTP. but, the problem existis when i play the video using HTTPS, in other words, the video don't works.

My application shows me that I have a certificate installed, but still shows me that the connection is not secure, is there any extra settings to perform on glassfish?

Regrats